My .dds textures doesnt appear on render viewport
I'm using blender 4.2 
And I exported a fbx model of a car with a folder of textures from assetto corsa.I wanted to practice blender with it 
Import went well, but the problem is that those .dds textures assigned to each meshes doesnt work. I searched some but seems like blender now support .dds 
So I cant figure out whats the problem. Help me to figure out how to use the model


I strongly suggest you do not start with Blender by importing a model. Importing typically is flawed and is its own puzzle if you already know Blender. It's like trying to learn to drive by practicing jumping into the driver's seat of a moving vehicle.

I agree with @TheLabCat that importing files from different software/formats is not always the best idea when you are still trying to figure out how Blender itself works. As said in the answer, you did not need to copy the texture node to use it for the Alpha for example. And have you even checked the Alpha channel if it has usable data that makes sense for the object? It looks like an engine hood and I don't see a reason why it should need Alpha transparency at all...

Thanks to both of your comments. I studied the basic recently so i wanted to see a tual use of what i learned. But i guess what i need is more solid background tho. Thanks

This is likely because the alpha channel in the DDS texture is being used for something else besides actual alpha. There is no reason to have that Image Texture node twice anyway, so delete the one connected to the Principled BSDF's Alpha input.

Thank you so much it works! I also appreciate of your comment about how i study too. But since the model includes tens of meshes with it, is there a way i can delete all those alpha nodes of all those meshes?

Yes, but I’ll have to look into it a bit. Basically use the Python API.
